# I want only numeric in my text box (I want only work with input id or class)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my input field, I want right a j query code for only numeric keyword type in this field. if user type string then can't do this .

```
<input type="tel" name="jobapp_phone" class="sjb-form-control sjb-phone-number sjb-required" id="jobapp_phone" required="required" autocomplete="off" placeholder="099876 54321">
```

Comment: type="number" ...

Comment: And you shouldnt use type="tel" as it isnt supported by many browsers...

Comment: Keep in mind that users can mess with your front end code to change the input to textual at any time, therefor, you should always validate server-side as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> check this it allows only numbers in the text field

```js
$(function() {
  $('#main').on('keydown', '#onlyNumbers', function(e){-1!==$.inArray(e.keyCode,[46,8,9,27,13,110,190])||/65|67|86|88/.test(e.keyCode)&&(!0===e.ctrlKey||!0===e.metaKey)||35<=e.keyCode&&40>=e.keyCode||(e.shiftKey||48>e.keyCode||57<e.keyCode)&&(96>e.keyCode||105<e.keyCode)&&e.preventDefault()});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
 <input id="onlyNumbers" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: ganes this is awesome  i got it what i want

Comment: Thank u... sanjay yadav

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```